# Changing imagebutton image(from gallery) with longclick

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-imagebutton

I've searched the forums, but not have found any specific or understandable answers for my problem.

I'd like to change my Imagebutton image to a picture, selected from the gallery. Prefferrably the image should stay changed after closing the application.

My XML for the button is here:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/eat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/eat"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

The java code for playing the sound is here with the OnClick method.

```
    ImageButton eat = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.eat);
    eat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp1.start();
        }
    });
```

I would like to add the OnLongClick method here too, (since to OnClick is allready taken and the image replacing should be a little different), but havent found the right way. Can You please guide me a little bit?

Comment: You need to return true from onLongClickListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return true from image's onLongClickListener.

Like this:

```
eat.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //do something
        return true;
    }

});

eat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp1.start();
    }
});
```

This will not cause the image's onClickListener to be called as it means that the action has already been handled in longClickListener.

Comment: Thank you..it works. But not to my other question.
Is it possible to add a picture from the gallery over there and replace the original image?
My code in the onClickListsener is here:

@Override
      public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

       int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
        Intent i = new Intent(
                      Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                      android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

              startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
This only lets me pick the image but doesnt replace it.Can You help?
       
          return true;
      }